# Grafana Cloud Synthetics monitoring check for SMTP with STARTTLS

Tags: grafana, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

In Grafana Cloud, I want to set up a Synthetics Monitoring check for SMTP with STARTTLS.

I setup the following Query/Response block and was expecting that the  `probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry` metric is not logged and displayed in the dashboard.
[image: Query/Response block]

However, the dashboard shows "No data" in the "SSL Expiry" panel.

Furthermore, if I add a third expected pattern to the Query/Response block, the checks will fail.
[image: Query/Response block]

However when I run a [Blackbox Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter) (which is what Grafana Synthetics monitoring is based on) locally with the following config, the check succeeds and the `probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry` metric is logged.

```
prober: tcp
http:
  ip_protocol_fallback: true
  follow_redirects: true
  enable_http2: true
tcp:
  preferred_ip_protocol: ip4
  ip_protocol_fallback: true
  query_response:
  - expect: 220 .+ ESMTP
  - send: STARTTLS
  - expect: 220 .+ Ready to start TLS
  - starttls: true
  - send: EHLO bb.info
  - expect: 250
```

Comment: Synthetic monitoring is custom code. I wouldn't use blackbox exporter as a reference. You can check source code https://github.com/grafana/synthetic-monitoring-agent to see if your case is implemented.